# function remove a word depending of a number - c programming

Tags: c, string, algorithm, function, pointers

I have been stuck with this problem over 4 days:

Write​ ​a​ ​function​ ​​skipWords()​ ​​that​ ​takes​ ​a​ ​string​ ​named​ ​​sentence​​ ​and​ ​an​ ​integer named​ ​​words​ ​​as​ ​arguments.​ ​The​ ​function​ ​should​ ​return​ ​a​ ​​pointer
​ ​ ​to​ ​a​ ​substring​ ​of sentence​.​ ​The​ ​function​ ​should​ ​skip​ ​the​ ​number​ ​of​ ​words​ ​indicated​ ​by​ ​the​ ​parameter words.

If​ ​words​ ​is,​ ​for​ ​instance,​ ​0,​ ​then​ ​a​ ​pointer​ ​to​ ​the​ ​beginning​ ​of​ ​the​ ​string​ ​​sentence​ ​​should be​ ​returned​ ​(that​ ​is,​ ​no​ ​words​ ​are​ ​skipped).​ ​If​ ​words​ ​is​ ​1,​ ​then​ ​a​ ​pointer​ ​to​ ​the​ ​second word​ ​of​ ​​sentence​ ​​should​ ​be​ ​returned​ ​(i.e.,​ ​one​ ​word​ ​is​ ​skipped),​ ​​etc
​ .​ ​To​ ​see​ ​how​ ​it should​ ​work,​ ​see​ ​the​ ​example​ ​below.​ ​The​ ​function​ ​may​ ​not​ ​print​ ​anything​ ​on​ ​the​ ​screen​ ​or take​ ​any​ ​input​ ​from​ ​the​ ​user.​ ​If​ ​​words​ ​​is​ ​greater​ ​or​ ​equal​ ​to​ ​the​ ​number​ ​of​ ​words​ ​in sentence​,​ ​then​ ​the​ ​pointer​ ​NULL​ ​should​ ​be​ ​returned.

Example: `char​​ ​*ptr1,​ ​*ptr2,​ ​*ptr3,​ ​*ptr4;
 ptr1​ ​=​ ​skipWords(​“there​ ​you​ ​go”​,​ ​1);​​ ​/*​ ​ptr1​ ​points​ ​to​ ​“you​ ​go”​ ​*/ 
ptr2​ ​=​ ​skipWords(​“there​ ​you​ ​go”​,​ ​2);​​ ​/*​ ​ptr2​ ​points​ ​to​ ​“go”​ ​*/ 
ptr3​ ​=​ ​skipWords(​“a​ ​string”​,​ ​0);​ ​​/*​ ​ptr3​ ​points​ ​to​ ​“a​ ​string”​ ​*/ 
ptr4​ ​=​ ​skipWords(​“a​ ​word”​,​ ​2);​ ​​/*​ ​ptr4​ ​is​ ​NULL​ ​*/`

got the code :

```
int skipWords(char sentence[], int words)
{
    int i;
    int len;

    len =strlen(sentence);

    if(words == 0)
    {
        sentence[i];
    }

    if(words == 1 && words<len)
    {

    *newsentence[i]=sentence[i];
    while (isalpha(newsentence[i])) //checking for the first blank space
    {
        i++;
    }
    newsentence[i] = '\0';

    *sentence[i]= newsentence[i]-i++;   //new string without the first word
    }

    if(words == 2 && len<words)
    {

    *newsentence[i]=sentence[i];
    // and i am lost


    else if (words>=len)
        *sentence=NULL;

}

int main()
{

    char *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptr3, *ptr4;
    ptr1= skipWords("there you go", 1);
    ptr2=skipWords("there you go", 2);
    ptr3=skipWords("a string", 0);
    ptr4=skipWords("a word",2);

    printf("%s\n", ptr1);
    printf("%s\n", ptr2);
    printf("%s\n", ptr3);
    printf("%s\n", ptr4);

    return 0;
}
```

but I am completely lost.

Comment: [`strchr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strchr.html) may help you (for a 1st attempt, assuming well-formed input).

Comment: If you are stuck with your code, why don't you show it? We cannot help you with code we can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We beginners should help each other.:)

Here you are

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * skipWords( const char *s, size_t n )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        while ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++s;

        do
        {
            while ( *s && !isblank( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++s;
            while ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++s;
        } while ( *s && --n );
    }

    return ( char * ) ( *s ? s : NULL );
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptr3, *ptr4;

    ptr1 = skipWords( "there you go", 1);

    if ( ptr1 ) puts( ptr1 );
    else puts( "NULL" );

    ptr2 = skipWords( "there you go", 2 );

    if ( ptr2 ) puts( ptr2 );
    else puts( "NULL" );

    ptr3 = skipWords( "a string", 0 );

    if ( ptr3 ) puts( ptr3 );
    else puts( "NULL" );

    ptr4 = skipWords( "a word", 2);

    if ( ptr4 ) puts( ptr4 );
    else puts( "NULL" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
you go
go
a string
NULL
```

As for your code then for starters the function should be declared at least like

```
char * skipWords(char sentence[], int words);
^^^^^^
```

instead of

```
int skipWords(char sentence[], int words);
^^^
```

and even in the very beginning of the code there is used uninitialized variable `i`  that produces undefined behavior of the program.

```
int i;
int len;

len =strlen(sentence);

if(words == 0)
{
    sentence[i];
            ^^^^
}
// ...
```

Comment: I'm all for walking a pointer, but `strtok` shure would make things "falling over a log, but not half as dangerous" -- easy `:)`

Comment: I wonder if you can tell me more about the return in the function

Comment: @havtorn This statement  return ( char * ) ( *s ? s : NULL );
  can be rewritten like if ( *s != '\0' ) return s; else return NULL;

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of those `​“` from your code, and use `"` instead.
Secondly,

```
if(words == 0)
{
    sentence[i];
}
```

This is dwelling with Undefined Behavior, since `i` is not initialized. 
Additionally, if you compile your code with warning turned on, your compiler will generate a warning stating something like `expression has no effect` or similar. It means that `sentence[i];` has no effect on anything.
Also, with warning turned on, your compiler would have also generated a warning which states something like `variable "i" is used before its value is set` or similar.

Do you realize that it all boils down to the requirement of locating a white-space in the input string, and then skip it the no. of times specified as a second argument?

All, you need to do is locate a white-space char in string.
For that, read the man page for a standard library function [`strchr`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr).

There are also ways to do it, without using the `strchr` function.
This one is the crude way of doing it, remember not the best way, but easier one for you to understand and optimize/improvise going ahead.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *skipWords(char* pStr, unsigned int uiWordsToSkip);

int main() {

    char *p1 = NULL, *p2 = NULL, *p3 = NULL, *p4 = NULL;
    char *crap = "I can not code at all!";

    p1 = skipWords(crap, 3);
    if(p1 != NULL)
        printf("\nFirst go: %s", p1);

    p2 = skipWords(crap, 2);
    if(p2 != NULL)
        printf("\nSecond go: %s", p2);

    p3 = skipWords(crap, 1);
    if(p3 != NULL)
        printf("\nThird go: %s", p3);

    p4 = skipWords(crap, 0);
    if(p4 != NULL)
        printf("\nFinal go: %s", p4);
}

char *skipWords(char* pStr, unsigned int uiWordsToSkip)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *p = pStr, *pTemp = NULL;

    const char ch = 0x20; //Hex for White Space in ASCII

    if(pStr == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < uiWordsToSkip; i++)
    {
        p = strchr(p, ch);
        if(p== NULL)
        {
            return pTemp ;
        }
        pTemp = p;
        p++;
    }

    return p;
}
```

Produces an output:

```
First go: code at all!
Second go: not code at all!
Third go: can not code at all!
Final go: I can not code at all!
```

Comment: wll cause UB if `strchr()` returns NULL

Comment: @WedaPashi  What about the space character '\x40'?:)

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt: Indeed. Instead of a bullet-proof code, I intended to keep it simple for OP and then OP could improvise as and when required.

Comment: it is required by the last example

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Sir, well-spotted! Oh, I thought I was supposed provide him a simple example.